# How do I avoid __init__ dependencies with MagicMock

Tags: python

I've gone through a few iterations of trying to reproduce this issue in my non-prod code. I think I have the situation nailed down here.

Basically, I am having a problem getting patch() to replace `LegacyClassCollaborator` in the below code

structure of the project

```
main.py
module1/__init__.py
module1/module2/__init__.py
module1/module2/module3.py
```

main.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, Mock
from module1.module2.module3 import LegacyClassCollaborator

class ClassUnderTest:
    def method_to_test(self):
        return LegacyClassCollaborator('file name').collab_call()

class TestWithMocks(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method_to_test(self):
        with patch('module1.module2.module3.LegacyClassCollaborator') as MockCollaborator:
            mock_instance = MockCollaborator.return_value
            mock_instance.collab_call = MagicMock(return_value='mocked string')

            cut = ClassUnderTest()
            assert cut.method_to_test() == 'mocked string'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

module3.py

```
class LegacyClassCollaborator:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        raise Exception('do not hit this')

    def collab_call(self):
        return 'unmocked string'
```

I get this error because it tries to use the unmocked `__init__` inside `LegacyClassCollaborator`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdpeckham/projects/pytesting/main.py", line 17, in test_method_to_test
    assert cut.method_to_test() == 'mocked string'
  File "/Users/jdpeckham/projects/pytesting/main.py", line 7, in method_to_test
    return LegacyClassCollaborator('file name').collab_call()
  File "/Users/jdpeckham/projects/pytesting/module1/module2/module3.py", line 3, in __init__
    raise Exception('do not hit this')
Exception: do not hit this
```

Comment: The class isn't under test if you mock the entire thing. You are just testing your mock's configuration.

Comment: The better solution is to stop accessing the file system from inside `Foo.__init__`. If you are opening a file, pass an already open file handle to `__init__` rather than a file name. This makes `Foo` much easier to test.

Comment: @chepner i could update my example to help illustrate the interdependencies. thanks for that feedback. in my case foo calls another class. give me a moment to update. and yes obviously it's better to not do such work in the constructor but in this case i have legacy code that i cannot change.

Comment: The next best thing to do would be to look at what inside `main.Foo.__init__` is hitting the file system, and mocking *that*. You don't mock the thing you want to test. The more you change `Foo`, the less meaningful any test based on `Foo` becomes.

Comment: @chepner hopefully my updates have cleared up some of the confusion I caused with my original. Basically, i think i am dealing with a module targeting issue because I was able to get this type of logic to work in a more pure example, but this module structure is confusing the patch() method

Comment: i think i maybe read a key part of this on https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object ... i need to target `__main__. LegacyClassCollaborator ` because that's the site of import

Answer (score 0):

You can always inherit from `Foo` to bypass its `__init__()` method:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
```

Now you can test `Bar`:

```
class TestWithMocks(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method_to_test(self):
            foo = Bar('blah')
            assert foo.method_to_test() == 'mocked string'
```

Comment: Yea, i could if i could control the site of injection of that subclass. I cannot. I am sorry my illustration was innacurate.